# issue in spring security saml extension with ADFS about the XML ID

Tags: java, spring, adfs

everyone~!recently I have built a project use spring security saml extension as SP and ADFS as idp,and the AuthnRequest xml created by the spring security saml extension is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://127.0.0.1:8080/sp"
    ForceAuthn="false" ID="9135430817744047388" IsPassive="false"
    IssueInstant="2016-11-17T06:20:05.912Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    Version="2.0">
    <samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        test
    </samlp:Issuer>
    <saml2p:NameIDPolicy
        xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AllowCreate="true"/>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

when I sent this SAMLRequest to the ADFS server,the server response an error which like "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder" and has no assertion content.For test , i wrote some java code with OpenSAML to create the AuthnRequest xml,and I change the attribute

> ID="9135430817744047388"

to

> ID="_9135430817744047388"

then everything works well.It seems that the character `_` in the ID will effect the result.
So my problem is ,how can I change the ID attribute in spring security saml extension to add `_` in the front of the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a mistake,there is no matter with the character `_` but the sign type of the request，as the metadatagenerator’s attribute `requestSigned` is set to **true** as default，spring saml will add `SigAlg` and `Signature` parameter in the http post request，and then adfs server will check the SP’s cert registered in the IDP,while I don’t supply the client cert to the IDP.
Resolution:set the attribute `requestSigned` to **false**,so spring saml won’t send the signature of the SAMLRequest and everything work correctly.